# SQL Server and Linked Tables (Similar to Access)

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I'm coming from an environment where I have used only MS Access and have linked spreadsheets as tables - the spreadsheets are updated daily then "ETL'd" and sent into various tables in Access via SQL queries that I've written.

Is there a way to do that in SQL server?  I am brand new to SQL Server and although I can write a mean query - I don't know the SSMS environment intimately yet.

Thanks!

Comment: [SSIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/sql-server-integration-services?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSIS, but for simple tasks, I often use views and `OPENROWSET` (or just `OPENROWSET` in queries), to query external sources. For example:

```
CREATE VIEW MyExcelFile
AS
SELECT rs.*
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;Database=C:\path\to\my\file.xlsx',
    'SELECT * FROM [SomeNamedRange$]') rs
```

This does require the Excel file to be accessible from the server, of course. It uses the Access Database Engine to query the Excel file. Note that some DBA's prohibit ad hoc access to the Access Database Engine for security reasons.

Comment: I'll check that out - and yes, our IT has the clamp down on SQL Server.  Was just happy to get a database provisioned!  Thanks for the response, I'm literally just getting back to this!